# How are "ace maneuvers" different from other maneuvers?

Tags: ace-patrol

When upgrading a pilot, they can typically learn a single "ace maneuver", like Wingover or Jink, or a collection of related maneuvers like various rolls.  Is there any special distinction between an ace maneuver and any other, beyond this fact that they're relatively expensive to learn?  Are there, for example, limits on when or how often they can be used (beyond normal limits on high-G maneuvers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of the ace maneuvers are far more "powerful" than other maneuvers, for lack of a better term.  There will be special restrictions on the maneuvers, as indicated on the card for the maneuver.  For instance, a Full Loop causes you to lose altitude (meaning you must be above altitude 2), you cannot shoot while performing the maneuver, and you must be flying straight and level before you start.

As an example of what I mean by more "powerful" - without knowing any special maneuvers, it takes three turns for a plane to make a 180 degree turn using Bank Left or Bank Right.  Adding in the Loop and Roll maneuver sets allow you to make a 180 degree turn in two moves (Half Loop + Half Loop).  The ace maneuvers Wingover, Split-S and Immelman allow you to make a 180 degree turn in a single move.  So if you start facing an enemy aircraft that does not know any ace maneuvers, you can let it pass you and then make a one move 180 degree turn to get on its tail.

The full list of ace maneuvers is as follows:

**Crack Shot** - A more powerful version of flying straight and level, as it causes more damage.

**Immelman**, **Split-S**, **Wingover** - All of these are one turn 180 degree turns.  The only real difference is the hex you end up in after the maneuver is over.

**Jink**, **Falling Leaf** - Defensive maneuvers that leave you in one spot facing a random direction (which is a good thing if you have an enemy directly behind you).

**Full Loop** - Allows you stay in the same hex, facing the same direction.  An enemy plane directly behind you will be forced to fly ahead of you, unless they have a similar maneuver.

**Full Roll Right** - A defensive maneuver that moves you quickly ahead and over a hex.